# sscanf not working right?

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to parse a URL, and wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char host[100];
    char port[100];
    char path[100];
    char prot[100];
    char* url = "https://google.com:8000/foobar";
    sscanf(url, "%s://%s:%s/%s", prot, host, port, path);
    printf("Protocol: %s\n", prot);
    printf("Host:     %s\n", host);
    printf("Port:     %s\n", port);
    printf("Path:     %s\n", path);

    return 0;
}
```

However, it outputs this:

```
Protocol: https://google.com:8000/foobar
Host:     å0&TFaa
Port:     
Path:
```

I'm not sure why it is putting all of my string into the protocol variable, instead of putting the correct parts into each variable.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sscanf` is greedy. It reads as many characters as it can.

Change it to use:

```
char* url = "https://google.com:8000/foobar";
sscanf(url, "%[^:]://%[^:]:%[^/]/%s", prot, host, port, path);
```

Answer (score 7):

The `sscanf()` format with `"%s"` is greedy so it will match as much as possible.

You also need to check the return value of `sscanf()` It is returning one.

Please look up the manual page. Perhaps the format `"%[^:]"` is what you are looking for.